# excel if true then a and b and c

Tags: excel, excel-2010, vba

I am using MS Excel 2010 want what to change a number of cells if a value is true e.g. `a2 =2`, `b2=1`, `c2=$30`, `d2=10`

```
    A       B       C       D
1   Prz     Stat    Val     Pts
2   2       1       $30     10
```

How do I do the following in Excel `IF B2=1 THEN A2+1 AND C2+30 AND D2+5` so that the above cells are changed to :-

```
    A       B       C       D
1   Prz     Stat    Val     Pts
2   3       1       $60     15
```

e.g. `a2=3`, `c2=60`, `d2=15`

Comment: Is there an "initial value" for the cells `A2`, `C2`, and `D2`? You should have a formula for each cell. For example, `A2` would have `=(initial)+B2` and `C2` would have `=(initial)+30*B2`, etc. That is to say, there's a starting condition of the spreadsheet cells, then there's an "event" that changes them (the event being: `B2` changes). But it's not clear to me if that's what you are after.

Answer (score 0):

First select the sheet containing the data and run this simple macro:

```
Sub TestAndBump()
    If [B2] = 1 Then
        [A2] = [A2] + 1
        [C2] = [C2] + 30
        [D2] = [D2] + 5
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Gary/Agv, The TestandBump macro works for B2 i.e. it changes the values in A2, C2 and D2. I would like the macro to check cells B2 down to B50 and to change cells A2:A50, C2:C50 and D2:D50 accordingly. I have tried turning on "Use Relative References" but it didn't work. I have also tried using Absolute cell references in the macro but it didn't work. What am I doing wrong? How can I attach sample file to a comment to illustrate what I am trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

Using Gary's Student solution above, you could also put the macro on a worksheet change event:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
   If [B2] = 1 Then
        [A2] = [A2] + 1
        [C2] = [C2] + 30
        [D2] = [D2] + 5
    End If
End Sub
```

Put the code in the worksheet that contains your data. By doing this you don't have to run the macro everytime you change a number.